# Magento resource model not working

Tags: magento

I have the following code:

```
$recipients = Mage::getResourceModel('crm/crm_collection');
            $recipients->getSelect()
                    ->joinInner(array(
                        'link' => $recipients->getTable('crm/bulkMailLink'),
                    ), "link.crm_id = e.entity_id", array(
                        'link_id' => 'link.id',
                    ))
                    ->where("link.queue_id = ? AND link.sent_at IS NULL", $queue->getId());
            $recipients->addAttributeToSelect('title');
            $recipients->addAttributeToSelect('first_name');
            $recipients->addAttributeToSelect('chinese_name');
            $recipients->addAttributeToSelect('last_name');
            $recipients->addAttributeToSelect('email1');
            $recipients->addAttributeToFilter('email1', array('neq'=>''));
            $recipients->setPageSize(100);
            $recipients->setCurPage(1);
```

I then log the select statement that the code produces:

```
Mage::log("DEBUG: ".((string)$recipients->getSelect()));
```

The above produces a working sql query that executes perfectly in phpmyadmin and returns the results I expect.

I then log the count of $recipients

```
Mage::log("Loading recipients for queue: {$recipients->count()}");
```

And this is where the code stops. In actual fact it will not even log the message. If I comment out the above logging code and try do a

```
foreach ($recipients as $crm)
{
    var_dump($crm);
    die();
}
```

It will not get into the foreach. The parser will stop before the foreach.

And the worst is that NO error messages are printed. I am seriously stuck.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `count()` and `foreach` operations trigger the collection to actually `load()`, meaning that the query is executed, the result set is fetched, and each result is attempted to be set as `_data` on an instance of the collection's model class. After the item is realized, the collection class attempts to add it to its internal storage via `addItem()`.

I suspect that your collection is explicitly throwing an exception because there are duplicate primary keys in your result set; see [`Varien_Data_Collection::addItem()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php#L367) for the logic. Comment this out temporarily to test.

To resolve, change your query or override `addItem()` locally in your collection class.